# Which SFF comics first used a grawlix (symbol swearing)?

Tags: comics, history-of

I have a feeling that grawlixes were designed for comedy cartoons used in newspaper columns (although I can't find its exact origin; not talking about the term "grawlix" which I believe was coined in 1964). I am interested to know when SFF comics adopted grawlixes (which can be much before 1964).

There are several examples. Yes, our Deadpool is in the list:

[image: Deadpool grawlix]

Other examples:

[image: Grawlix 2]

[image: Spider-Man cursing]

Which SFF comics first used grawlixes?

Comment: We need a precise definition of "SFF comic" seeing as the first instances were probably in mainstream comic strips with SFF elements.

Comment: @user14111 It is difficult to see how superhero comics can be considered *not* SFF: certainly the prevalent space opera, super powers, mutants and magic fall under fantasy as a literary category.

Comment: @user14111, but surely a SFF comic **is SFF**. :) Also: no idea about the Katzenjammers (I know what they look like, but have never read them. :) Now if it was *Krazy Kat* I would give a resounding "YES!" to the question of SFF. :)

Comment: Hardly the earliest, but there is a grawlix in the 3rd panel of the *Li'l Abner* daily strip for 11/27/51. Of course the *Li'l Abner* comic had lots of SFF, most famously the shmoos.

Comment: Unrelated but where is that second panel from? Because there's [the almost same exact one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd8lH.jpg) in _Venom: Lethal Protector_ #2 (1993) so I'm wondering if that's a homage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR:** 1936. Answer goes from describing the one I found, how I found it, what could be an earlier instance, and ends on a treat for nitpickers.

---

I've done some research *(see below)* and the earliest one I can trace is this panel from "The Secret Ray", also known as "*Manitoba* no reply", the first issue of [*The adventures of Jo, Zette and Jocko*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Jo,_Zette_and_Jocko) by Belgian author Hergé, which was originally pre-published in the French weekly newspaper *Cœurs vaillants*.

The panel is dated from February 2, 1936. [Full page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3tBd.jpg), if you're curious.

[image: Coeurs Vaillants]

From where I stand, "The Secret Ray" qualifies as SFF in the sense that while *Adventures of Jo, Zette and Jocko* can feel like classic 1930s action-adventure stories for children, this particular story features:

1. An evil scientist who created a taser-like ray, as well as the title "secret ray", which he uses to put ships' crews to sleep and steal from them.

   [image: Taser-like ray]
2. A killer robot, creation of aforementioned scientist. The robot is remote-controlled, but is intended to be fully autonomous, the "first living being ever created", elevating its creator as a God.

   [image: Robot from "Manitoba no reply"]

---

#### Research done

I meant to randomly browse 40s-50s Marvel/DC comics at first, but I grew up with Franco-Belgian comics, and the grawlixes are recurrent in those. I found several in *Tintin* issues, which were also written and drawn by Hergé. Not all *Tintin* issues qualify as SFF though, so I went for "*Manitoba* no reply" which I knew was SFF.

Bingo, just had to trace back the original one from the 30s to make sure the grawlix wasn't added in the later reprints. Jackpot, it wasn't. :-)

---

#### So what could be an earlier instance?

- For the sake of completeness, let's mention [this *Slate* article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2013/10/09/the_grawlix_how_the_katzenjammer_kids_comic_strip_pioneered_the_use_of_typographical.html) which provides a 1902 grawlix from *Katzenjammer Kids* (not SFF as far as I know).
- The Hergé panel being dated from 1936, most classic comics franchises are out (Superman for instance debuted in 1938).
- user14111 mention *Li'l Abner* in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178185/which-sff-comics-first-used-a-grawlix#comment480667_178185), with a grawlix dated November 27, 1951. I've been through a good bunch of the 1934-1935 *Li'l Abner* strips (available on [this website](https://www.gocomics.com/lil-abner/1934/08/19)) and found none, though it's possible I missed one. However, the SFF element in this comic is apparently the Shmoos, which if I am to believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%27l_Abner#Shmoos_and_other_mythic_creatures) were only introduced in 1948.
- I don't have access to early *Tarzan* and *Mandrake the magician* comics, but grawlixes usually are a "comedy" thing, and from the little I know of these, they don't seem to qualify.
- There's a comic titled [*The Adventures of Patsy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Patsy) which involve a magical kingdom and a magician, and looks cartoonish. It debuted in 1934 though, so it's a narrow period to catch up to Hergé's 1936.

---

#### For nitpickers

Someone wants to argue that the 1936 panel isn't exactly profanity, and just the ship's captain's confusion (though it could be profanity - the captain's confusion was already depicted in the panel before)?

Fine, here's my second best. It's the earliest grawlix in *Tintin*'s issue "Prisoners of the Sun" (1948). Not the first grawlix in all *Tintin* issues, but the first in a SFF one.

[image: Haddock awoken by an anteater]